# SettingWithCopyWarning pandas using str.split

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to understand why the `SettingWithCopyWarning` is appearing here and how I can fix it. Here's my reproducible code:

```py
import pandas as pd
grants = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2023/2023-10-03/grants.csv', na_values = [" ", "Not Available"])
grants_sub = grants[(grants["expected_number_of_awards"] > 0) | (grants["estimated_funding"] > 0)]

## extract the year, month, and day
grants_sub[["year", "month", "day"]] = grants_sub["posted_date"].str.split(pat = "-", expand = True)
grants_sub
```

Which provides the following messages

```py
/var/folders/77/jqqmprj106jgtfpl96dr7910wy6yyk/T/ipykernel_81958/3239128668.py:11: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  grants_sub[["year", "month", "day"]] = grants_sub["posted_date"].str.split(pat = "-", expand = True)
/var/folders/77/jqqmprj106jgtfpl96dr7910wy6yyk/T/ipykernel_81958/3239128668.py:11: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  grants_sub[["year", "month", "day"]] = grants_sub["posted_date"].str.split(pat = "-", expand = True)
/var/folders/77/jqqmprj106jgtfpl96dr7910wy6yyk/T/ipykernel_81958/3239128668.py:11: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  grants_sub[["year", "month", "day"]] = grants_sub["posted_date"].str.split(pat = "-", expand = True)
```

I interpreted it (wrongly?) to use `.loc` instead, so if I do the following instead:

```py
grants_sub.loc[:, ["year", "month", "day"]] = grants_sub.loc[:,"posted_date"].str.split(pat = "-", expand = True)
grants_sub
```

It gives `NaN` for the year, month, and day columns.

Clearly this is an operator issue, so what am I doing wrong and why? The referenced page uses an example related to chaining and that chaining can result in slow performance or unexpected results, but the suggest `pd` fix here, doesn't work. I am guessing this is related to pandas being unsure if I want to work with a view or a copy, but I don't understand why.

Comment: You can force a copy in your boolean indexing with `grants_sub = grants[(grants["expected_number_of_awards"] > 0) | (grants["estimated_funding"] > 0)].copy()`

Comment: Interesting. So, the issue was the boolean indexing. Is there a correct way to do this filtering?

Comment: It was a correct way, but returning a view.